# Vuforia and Firebase sdk conflict creating Black Screen

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Vuforia SDK Version: 6-0-117 -

Description with steps to reproduce: When adding the aforementioned Vuforia 6-0-117 sdk and FirebaseMessaging sdk into an empty Unity 5.42 project, and building it into an iOS app, it seems to always conflict and create only a Black Screen. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thanks! -

Development OS (Mac OS X, Windows, Linux): Mac OS X -

Mobile OS and Version: iOS 10.2, S Code 8.2.1 -

Mobile Device Manufacturer and Model name: Apple iPhone 6 -

Do the Vuforia Sample Applications show the same behavior?: